# How to insert CSV data into an SQLite table via a shell pipe?

Tags: shell, pipe, csv, csv-simple, sqlite

I have written a program that outputs the result to the standard output in strict pure CSV form (every line represents a single record and contain the same set of comma-separated fields, fields only contain lowercase English letters, numbers and dots, no spaces, no quotes and no symbols that might need to be escaped/encoded).

How do I redirect this output into an SQLite table that it fits into perfectly?

It would be great if I could control whether I want constraint-breaking (e.g. having the same primary/secondary key as the records already in the table)  replace existing records or be discarded silently.

Of course I might build direct SQLite database output support in the program itself but I would prefer going the unix-way if possible.

Comment: Has outputted csv a header columns as the 1st line?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Not really. But of course covering both cases will make this Q&A more interesting.

Answer (score 9):

I found an even simpler solution that still uses [`sqlite3`](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) [`.import`](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_csv_files), but that doesn't read `/dev/stdin` or a temporary named pipe.  Instead, it uses `.import` with the [pipe operator](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#reading_sql_from_a_file) to invoke `cat -` to read directly from standard input.

```
#!/bin/bash

function csv_to_sqlite() {
  local database_file_name="$1"
  local table_name="$2"
  sqlite3 -csv $database_file_name ".import '|cat -' $table_name"
}

database_file_name=$1
table_name=$2

csv_to_sqlite "$database_file_name" "$table_name"
```

Note that this wouldn't work in a Windows command shell.

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches:

Sample `test.csv` file:

```
GroupName,Groupcode,GroupOwner,GroupCategoryID 
System Administrators,sysadmin,13456,100
Independence High Teachers,HS Teachers,,101
John Glenn Middle Teachers,MS Teachers,13458,102
Liberty Elementary Teachers,Elem Teachers,13559,103
1st Grade Teachers,1stgrade,,104
2nd Grade Teachers,2nsgrade,13561,105
3rd Grade Teachers,3rdgrade,13562,106
Guidance Department,guidance,,107
```

---

**1**) With **[csvkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/index.html)** (a suite of command-line tools for converting to and working with CSV)

Import into *sqlite3* database:

```
csvsql --db sqlite:///test_db --tables test_tbl --insert test.csv
```

If no input csv file was specified it'll accept csv data from stdin:

```
... | csvsql --db sqlite:///test_db --tables test_tbl --insert
```

To extract data from *sqlite* database:

```
sql2csv --db sqlite:///test_db --query 'select * from test_tbl limit 3'
```

The output:

```
GroupName,Groupcode,GroupOwner,GroupCategoryID 
System Administrators,sysadmin,13456,100
Independence High Teachers,HS Teachers,,101
John Glenn Middle Teachers,MS Teachers,13458,102
```

---

**2**) With **[sqlite3](https://sqlite.org/cli.html)** command-line tool (allows the user to manually enter and execute SQL statements against an *SQLite* database)

> Use the "`.import`" command to import CSV (comma separated value) data
>   into an SQLite table. The "`.import`" command takes two arguments which
>   are the name of the disk file from which CSV data is to be read and
>   the name of the SQLite table into which the CSV data is to be
>   inserted.
>
> Note that it is important to set the "mode" to "csv" before running
>   the "`.import`" command. This is necessary to prevent the command-line
>   shell from trying to interpret the input file text as some other
>   format.

```
$ sqlite3
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import test.csv test_tbl
sqlite> select GroupName,Groupcode from test_tbl limit 5;
"System Administrators",sysadmin
"Independence High Teachers","HS Teachers"
"John Glenn Middle Teachers","MS Teachers"
"Liberty Elementary Teachers","Elem Teachers"
"1st Grade Teachers",1stgrade
sqlite>
```

Comment: csvkit uses agate's from_csv, which, for reasons which are unclear to me, reads in the entire contents of stdin https://github.com/wireservice/agate/blob/4d4c3424839d8c813bc1ae429c9df95ea6cba85d/agate/table/from_csv.py#L65

Answer (score 3):

On Unix-like systems, the [`sqlite3`](https://sqlite.org/cli.html) command [`.import`](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_csv_files) can read CSV content from standard input from special file `/dev/stdin`:

```
$ printf "col1,col2\na,1\nb,2\n" | sqlite3 test.db ".import --csv /dev/stdin test"
$ sqlite3 -csv -header test.db "SELECT * FROM test"
col1,col2
a,1
$ sqlite3 -version
3.32.3 2020-06-18 14:00:33 7ebdfa80be8e8e73324b8d66b3460222eb74c7e9dfd655b48d6ca7e1933cc8fd
b,2
```

Comment: See simpler solution https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/642364/5783.

Answer (score 1):

The following bash function `csv_to_sqlite` reads CSV content from standard input and imports it into an SQLite database table using the [`sqlite3`](https://sqlite.org/cli.html) command [`.import`](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_csv_files) and a temporary named pipe (FIFO):

```
#!/bin/bash

function csv_to_sqlite() {
  local database_file_name="$1"
  local table_name="$2"
  local temp_input_fifo=$(mktemp -u)
  mkfifo $temp_input_fifo
  sqlite3 -csv $database_file_name ".import $temp_input_fifo $table_name" &
  cat > $temp_input_fifo
  rm $temp_input_fifo
}

database_file_name=$1
table_name=$2

csv_to_sqlite "$database_file_name" "$table_name"
```

```
$ printf "col1,col2,col3\na,1,2.6\nb,2,5.4\n" | ./csv_to_sqlite test.sqlite test
$ sqlite3 -csv -header test.sqlite "SELECT * FROM test"
col1,col2,col3
a,1,2.6
b,2,5.4
```

Comment: See simpler solution https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/642364/5783.